# How to convert a Python list into a sympy Add class?

Tags: python, class, sympy

I'm trying to write code that solves a Lagrangian multiplier but saves intermediate functions for later call back.

My error is in combining and solving the partial differentials. I think the error is in the output of the solver.

```
import sympy as smp

def R1(x):
  return 12*x-x**2

def R2(y):
  return 8*y-y**2

def R3(z):
  return 18*z-3*z**2

def G(L,x,y,z,h):
  return L*(x+y+z-h)


x = smp.Symbol('x')
y = smp.Symbol('y')
z = smp.Symbol('z')
L = smp.Symbol('L')
h = 10

H = smp.lambdify([x,y,z,L], R1(x)+R2(y)+R3(z)+G(L,x,y,z,h))

R1_prime = H(x,y,z,L).diff(x) 
R2_prime = H(x,y,z,L).diff(y) 
R3_prime = H(x,y,z,L).diff(z) 


R1_prime_f = smp.lambdify([x,L],R1_prime) 
R2_prime_f = smp.lambdify([y,L],R2_prime) 
R3_prime_f = smp.lambdify([z,L],R3_prime) 

LM = smp.lambdify(L,(smp.sympify(smp.solve(R1_prime_f(x,L),x))+
                     smp.sympify(smp.solve(R2_prime_f(y,L),y))+
                     smp.sympify(smp.solve(R3_prime_f(z,L),z))-h))

LMN = smp.solve(LM(L),L)

print(LMN)
```

My output is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-c72ae9c79af4> in <module>()
     31 LM = smp.lambdify(L,(smp.sympify(smp.solve(R1_prime_f(x,L),x))+
     32                      smp.sympify(smp.solve(R2_prime_f(y,L),y))+
---> 33                      smp.sympify(smp.solve(R3_prime_f(z,L),z))-h))
     34 
     35 LMN = smp.solve(LM(L),L)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: Could it be that you misplaced the "-h" part in line 33?

Comment: `solve` always returns a list, also when there is only 1 (or none) solution. If you are sure there is exactly one solution, you can use `smp.solve(R1_prime_f(x,L),x)[0]`. Also note that it is not necessary to use `lambdify` here. Just use the expressions as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`solve`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html) always returns a list, also when there is only 1 (or none) solution. If you are sure there is exactly one solution, you can use `solve(..., x)[0]`. Also note that it is not necessary to use `lambdify` here. Just use the expressions directly.

Here is how the code would look like without `lambdify`:

```py
import sympy as smp

def R1(x):
    return 12 * x - x ** 2

def R2(y):
    return 8 * y - y ** 2

def R3(z):
    return 18 * z - 3 * z ** 2

def G(L, x, y, z, h):
    return L * (x + y + z - h)

x = smp.Symbol('x')
y = smp.Symbol('y')
z = smp.Symbol('z')
L = smp.Symbol('L')
h = 10

H = R1(x) + R2(y) + R3(z) + G(L, x, y, z, h)

R1_prime = H.diff(x)
R2_prime = H.diff(y)
R3_prime = H.diff(z)

LM = smp.solve(R1_prime, x)[0] + smp.solve(R2_prime, y)[0] + smp.solve(R3_prime, z)[0] - h

LMN = smp.solve(LM, L)

print(LMN)  # [-18/7]
print(LMN[0].evalf())  # -2.57142857142857
```

PS: Note that with sympy it is not necessary to write the expressions as functions. All variables are automatically interpreted as is they were function parameters. Unlike some other symbolic math environments, sympy currently doesn't differentiate between parameters and symbolic variables.

Therefore, the code can also be written as follows.

```py
import sympy as smp

x, y, z, L = smp.symbols('x y z L')
h = 10

R1 = 12 * x - x ** 2
R2 = 8 * y - y ** 2
R3 = 18 * z - 3 * z ** 2
G = L * (x + y + z - h)
H = R1 + R2 + R3 + G

R1_prime = H.diff(x)
R2_prime = H.diff(y)
R3_prime = H.diff(z)

LM = smp.solve(R1_prime, x)[0] + smp.solve(R2_prime, y)[0] + smp.solve(R3_prime, z)[0] - h
LMN = smp.solve(LM, L)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what I'm doing.. but this seems to work

```py
R1_prime_f = smp.lambdify([x,L],R1_prime) 
R2_prime_f = smp.lambdify([y,L],R2_prime) 
R3_prime_f = smp.lambdify([z,L],R3_prime) 

LM = smp.lambdify(L,(smp.sympify(smp.solve(R1_prime_f(x,L),x)[0])+
                     smp.sympify(smp.solve(R2_prime_f(y,L),y)[0])+
                     smp.sympify(smp.solve(R3_prime_f(z,L),z)[0])-h))

LMN = smp.solve(LM(L),L)

print(LMN)
```

notice 0 index here `smp.sympify(smp.solve(R1_prime_f(x,L),x)[0]`